# WooCommerce - Issue overriding product price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am trying to override the price of certain products containing a selectbox I added. I've followed [this tutorial](https://sarkware.com/woocommerce-change-product-price-dynamically-while-adding-to-cart-without-using-plugins/) head to toe, and have been researching a fix for a while now.

**In my functions.php:**

```
function calculate_core_fee( $cart_object ) {
    if( !WC()->session->__isset( "reload_checkout" )) {
        /* core price */
        //$additionalPrice = WC()->session->get( 'coreCharge' );
        //echo $additionalPrice;
        $additionalPrice = 100;
        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
            if( isset( $value["addOn"] ) ) {                
                if( isset( $value['data']->price ) ) {
                    /* Version before 3.0 */
                    $orgPrice = floatval( $value['data']->price );

                    echo $orgPrice . " + ";
                    echo $additionalPrice . " = ";
                    $newPrice = $value['data']->price = ( $orgPrice + $additionalPrice );
                    echo $newPrice;

                    $value['data']->price = ( $orgPrice + $additionalPrice );
                } else {
                    /* Woocommerce 3.0 + */
                    $orgPrice = floatval( $value['data']->get_price() );

                    $value['data']->set_price( $orgPrice + $additionalPrice );
                }           
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_core_fee', 99 );
```

**Something strange:** The last if statement checks for version compatibility (*b/c Wooc 3.0 and up requires "->set_price" instead of "->price"*)... however, when I was echoing out the variables, it only worked for the "*Version before 3.0*".

I am currently using version 3.1.1 of WooCommerce. I am also using a cart.php template in my child theme, but I've updated it to the most recent version of the file.

**Here is the result of the echoed out variables:** 
[image]

I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: Why did you set the priority value to 99 in the add_action method?

Comment: It was from the tutorial, I figured out my issue though, thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out almost immediately after posting this... but here is the working code.

Functions.php:

```
function calculate_core_fee( $cart_object ) {
    if( !WC()->session->__isset( "reload_checkout" )) {
        /* core price */
        $additionalPrice = WC()->session->get( 'coreCharge' );
        //echo $additionalPrice;
        //$additionalPrice = 100;
        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
            if( isset( $value["addOn"] ) ) {                

                    /* Woocommerce 3.0 + */
                    $orgPrice = floatval( $value['data']->get_price() );
                    //echo $additionalPrice;
                    //echo $orgPrice;
                    $value['data']->set_price( $orgPrice + $additionalPrice );

            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_core_fee', 99 );
```

All I did was remove the code that checked if the object contained 'price' which has been changed since WooCommerce 3.0 and it magically worked.

Comment: If you're trying to do this w/ a static price, simply change $additionalPrice to the price you want to add. Here, I'm pulling the price from another product I store in a session var.